# How to create a custom Gmail filter?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I want to create a filter in Gmail: that the sender is A **AND** the receiver is B.

It seems to me that this kind of combined filter is not available.

How to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not possible with the basic Gmail filter options? I think it should be:
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579

Just make sure you enter an address in the `From` field AND the `To` field.

> Gmail's filters allow you to manage the flow of incoming messages.
>   Using filters, you can automatically label, archive, delete, star, or
>   forward your mail, even keep it out of Spam.
>
> **To create a filter**
>
> 1. Click the down arrow in your search box. A window that allows you to
>      specify your search criteria will appear.
> 2. Enter your search criteria.
>      If you want to check that your search worked correctly, click the
>      search button.
> 3. Click Create filter with this search at the bottom of
>      the search window. If you need to verify the search results, you can
>      click the x to collapse the filter options. Clicking the down arrow
>      again will bring the window back with the same search criteria you
>      entered.
> 4. Choose the action(s) you want the filter to take.
>
>    - To keep
>        organized, many people like to have incoming messages automatically
>        labeled and removed from their inbox until they can look at them later
>        at a more convenient time. If you want to do this, make sure to select
>        Skip the Inbox (Archive it) and Apply the label: when you create your
>        filter.
> 5. Click the Create filter button.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I think gmail makes a confusion here. In order to do this, a "AND" has to be put in the field of "HAS THE WORD", actually, this is nothing to do with "has the word", but this AND is a special keyword. Thanks anyway

Comment: If it's working for you, great! Although I don't think the "Has the words" field has anything to do with it, but I'm glad it started working regardless :)

Comment: You know what, I use this to take note with gmail, send a email to myself. :) I am suprised that gmail cant take notes.